# How to avoid EOF while sending data and closing socket?

Tags: java, sockets, eof

I need to conditionally send some data over the net. I have ran in strange problem that my connection looks like beeing closed before whole data is send.

Server

```
String id = String.valueOf(dis.readLong());
String path = createPathToFile(id);
File image = getFile(path);

if (image == null) {
    log.debug("No image for id {}", id);
    dos.writeBoolean(false);
    dos.flush();
    return;
} else {
    log.debug("Streaming #{}", image.getName());
```

As you can see, I want to send logical `false` to client before closing connection (socket is closed in `finally` block

However on the client side i have following error

```
19:40:29.914 [pool-1-thread-1] ERROR [l.choina.imagetransfer.client.Client] - Fatal:
java.io.EOFException: null
        at java.io.DataInputStream.readBoolean(DataInputStream.java:244) ~[na:1.7.0_55]
        at pl.choina.imagetransfer.client.Client$WorkerTask.run(Client.java:98) ~[image-transfer.jar:na]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) [na:1.7.0_55]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) [na:1.7.0_55]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0_55]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_55]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_55]
```

It looks like the socket is closed before boolean value hits the client sie.

Client

```
try (
    Socket s = new Socket(params.getHost(), params.getPort());
    DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
    DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
) {
    //connect to remote host
    dos.writeLong(id);
    dos.flush();
    boolean result = dis.readBoolean(); // line 98 - throwing exception

    if (result == false) {
        log.info("Image #{} not available", id);
```

Why is this happening? Do I have to close socket on server side and would it be autoclosed when I close socket on client side? If I leave it be, everything works fine, but what about resoure leaking than?

Comment: well at the time you read the boolean, the server might haven't wrote the boolean yet... use dis.available() before reading to check if has any data

Comment: But `readBoolean()` is blocking operation so it would wait for something to be sent.I don't think this is not the issue.

Comment: Exactly. @fmodos There are few correct uses of available(), and that isn't one of them.

Comment: Are you sure you're writing the Boolean? Does that longline get logged? It looks to me as though the socket is getting closed prior to this step.

Comment: You are correct, socket is supposed to get close after sending `false`, because there will be no futher communication - socket is closed on server side in finally block. Client however do not receive `boolean` but get noticed about connection beeing closed. Should't closing socket send some kind of EOF? Is it a difference between closing socket and closing output stream? Maybe I should close output stream by hand after sending `false` and later on close socket?